# SpringMvc:About encoding of requestMapping method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, encoding

I have a trouble about SpingMvc encoding, I run the test case like this:

```
@Test
public void testSearch(){
System.out.println(MusicUtil.getSongsDetail(MusicUtil.getMusicIds(MusicUtil.search("呵呵", 10, 1, 1))))
}
```

then result likes this:
`...name":"一西米"...`

but in the method that has RequestMapping annotation,result is different from test case's result,this is code:

```
@RequestMapping("/search")
public void search() {
 System.out.println(MusicUtil.getSongsDetail(MusicUtil.getMusicIds(MusicUtil.search("呵呵", 10, 1, 1))))
}
```

but this result is `..."name":"�?西米"...`

Why?
How to resolve this problem.

Comment: Are you using maven? If so please specify the encoding you given there.

Comment: yes, I use maven and spring-boot,I don't set anything about encoding,I think the default encoding is utf-8

Comment: I use utf-8 encoding print the result in cmd,only a few chinese characters is not normal.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following property in your pom.xml and rebuild

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    ...
</properties>
```

If you do not set this property then default encoding will be taken from your system settings.

Comment: I use this setting,but it is the same as before :(